# How to change theorem display citation style right after thmhead

Tags: formatting

I would like to change the display style of 'citation' in a theorem using 'book' class. For example, by default, it would display

```
\begin{theorem}\cite{pS97}
    <theorem-content>
\end{theorem}
```

as

**Theorem 1.** *[11]* <*theorem-content*>.

How to change the display style of citation in the Theorem to be straight (not italic)? The result as my expectation should be:

**Theorem 1.** [11] <*theorem-content*>.

Comment: You need to provide us with some indication of how you created these theorems. What theorem-related package might you be using? [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)?

Comment: Did you try a plain `\textup{cite{p597}}`?

Comment: You mind ``\textup{\cite{p597}}``?

Comment: do you always want citation info to be upright? (that could be done, but is somewhat more complicated,)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: yes, I do want everytime I cite to a document, the related one will always displayed upright.

Comment: @Werner: I did use the amsthm, but to create the theorem-like-structure, I only use the normal one as: \newtheorem{}{} and do not declare anything more than that.

Comment: I found a way to do it by creating new `code`\theoremstyle`code` using the **amsthm** package from the book *The LaTeX Companion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a method that will set *all* `\cite`s upright, regardless of where they may occur.  it will, as coded here, *not* set an optional element upright, but that is easy to change if desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{\textup[{\textup{#1}\if@tempswa \textup, #2\fi}\textup]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\cite{p597}
    Theorem content.
\end{theorem}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{p597}
  Text of bib item.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]